# Jmeter: Extracting JSON response with special/spaces characters

Tags: json, api, jmeter, automated-tests, httpresponse

Hello can someone help me extract the value of user parameter which is "testuser1"

I tried to use this JSON Path expression $..data I was able to extract the entire response but unable to extract user parameter. Thanks in advance

{
"data": "{  "took" : 13,  "timed_out" : false,  "_shards" : {    "total" : 5,    "successful" : 5,    "skipped" : 0,    "failed" : 0  },  "hits" : {    "total" : 1,    "max_score" : 1.0,    "hits" : [      {        "_index" : "bushidodb_history_network_eval_ea9656ef-0a9b-474b-8026-2f83e2eb9df1_2021-april-10",        "_type" : "network",        "_id" : "6e2e58be-0ccf-3fb4-8239-1d4f2af322e21618059082000",        "_score" : 1.0,        "_source" : {          "misMatches" : [            "protocol",            "state",            "command"          ],          "instance" : "e3032804-4b6d-3735-ac22-c827950395b4|0.0.0.0|10.179.155.155|53|UDP",          "protocol" : "UDP",          "localAddress" : "0.0.0.0",          "localPort" : "12345",          "foreignAddress" : "10.179.155.155",          "foreignPort" : "53",          "command" : "ping yahoo.com ",          "user" : "testuser1",          "pid" : "10060",          "state" : "OUTGOINGFQ",          "rate" : 216.0,          "originalLocalAddress" : "192.168.100.229",          "exe" : "/bin/ping",          "md5" : "f9ad63ce8592af407a7be43b7d5de075",          "dir" : "",          "agentId" : "abcd-dcd123",          "year" : "2021",          "month" : "APRIL",          "day" : "10",          "hour" : "12",          "time" : "1618059082000",          "isMerged" : false,          "timestamp" : "Apr 10, 2021 12:51:22 PM",          "metricKey" : "6e2e58be-0ccf-3fb4-8239-1d4f2af322e2",          "isCompliant" : false        },        "sort" : [          1618059082000        ]      }    ]  },  "aggregations" : {    "count_over_time" : {      "buckets" : [        {          "key_as_string" : "2021-04-10T08:00:00.000-0400",          "key" : 1618056000000,          "doc_count" : 1        }      ]    }  }}",
"success": true,
"message": {
"code": "S",
"message": "Get Eval results Count Success"
}
}

Actual Response:

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbZRN.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you format  your code to improve its readability?

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Are you *sure* this is **exactly** what you're supposed to have? It seems you removed the backslashes that is shown in that screenshot. Can you take another stab at posting the correct JSON as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you posted doesn't look like a valid JSON to me.

If in reality you're getting what's in your image, to wit:

```
{
  "data": "{ \"took\" : 13, \"timed_out\" : false, \"_shards\" : { \"total\" : 5, \"successful\" : 5, \"skipped\" : 0, \"failed\" : 0 }, \"hits\" : { \"total\" : 1, \"max_score\" : 1.0, \"hits\" : [ { \"_index\" : \"bushidodb_history_network_eval_ea9656ef-0a9b-474b-8026-2f83e2eb9df1_2021-april-10\", \"_type\" : \"network\", \"_id\" : \"6e2e58be-0ccf-3fb4-8239-1d4f2af322e21618059082000\", \"_score\" : 1.0, \"_source\" : { \"misMatches\" : [ \"protocol\", \"state\", \"command\" ], \"instance\" : \"e3032804-4b6d-3735-ac22-c827950395b4|0.0.0.0|10.179.155.155|53|UDP\", \"protocol\" : \"UDP\", \"localAddress\" : \"0.0.0.0\", \"localPort\" : \"12345\", \"foreignAddress\" : \"10.179.155.155\", \"foreignPort\" : \"53\", \"command\" : \"pingyahoo.com\", \"user\" : \"testuser1\", \"pid\" : \"10060\", \"state\" : \"OUTGOINGFQ\", \"rate\" : 216.0, \"originalLocalAddress\" : \"192.168.100.229\", \"exe\" : \"/bin/ping\", \"md5\" : \"f9ad63ce8592af407a7be43b7d5de075\", \"dir\" : \"\", \"agentId\" : \"abcd-dcd123\", \"year\" : \"2021\", \"month\" : \"APRIL\", \"day\" : \"10\", \"hour\" : \"12\", \"time\" : \"1618059082000\", \"isMerged\" : false, \"timestamp\" : \"Apr10, 202112: 51: 22PM\", \"metricKey\" : \"6e2e58be-0ccf-3fb4-8239-1d4f2af322e2\", \"isCompliant\" : false }, \"sort\" : [ 1618059082000 ] } ] }, \"aggregations\" : { \"count_over_time\" : { \"buckets\" : [ { \"key_as_string\" : \"2021-04-10T08: 00: 00.000-0400\", \"key\" : 1618056000000, \"doc_count\" : 1 } ] } }}",
  "success": true,
  "message": {
    "code": "S",
    "message": "Get Eval results Count Success"
  }
}
```

the easiest way is just using 2 [JSON Extractors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor):

1. Extract `data` attribute value into a JMeter Variable from the response

   [image]
2. Extract `user` attribute value into a JMeter variable from `${data}` JMeter Variable:

   [image]

Demo:

[image]

If the response looks like exactly you posted you won't be able to use JSON Extractors and will have to treat it as normal text so your choice is limited to [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), example regular expression:

```
"user"\s*:\s*"(\w+)"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I tried your solution and it works on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Add Regular Expression extractor with the corresponding request and extract it. Use the below expression.
Expression: "user" : "(.*?)"

Ref: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html

[Regular Expression Extractor Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTJwy.jpg)

Comment: as much as possible I tried to avoid regular expression because it has a special character and difficult to filter since this is a JSON response. as you see on the screenshot I attached

Comment: Use this expression, it maybe helps you.
JSON Expression:  "$.data.hits.hits.[*]._source.user".

Your JSON response is quite complicated. Just copy your JSON response and paste it to any JSON beautifier, it gets thrown error as invalid JSON.  However, I tried with your response and cannot find any parameter value. 
I just get the value after fixing the JSON.
You can validate that expression from https://jsonpath.com/ this site.  Thank you.