# Jmeter extracting the response value and use on the same HTTP Sampler name

Tags: jmeter, response, preprocessor

Can someone help me extract the name parameter and use that on the same HTTP request name

Example if this is the response I got

```
{
    "response_time": 0.014376163482666016,
    "applications": [
        {
            "uid": "gta",
            "api_key": "blted0e7982e1cf62a8",
            "account_name": "jack",
            "name": "Testuser"
        }
    ]
}
```

the name HTTP Request name depends on the name parameter will be generated

[image: Image Description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) as a child of the request (as per [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) you need something which is executed after the JSON Extractor post-processor)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + ' ' + vars.get('name'))
   ```
3. That's it, now you will have `${name}` JMeter Variable added as the postfix for the sampler name

   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much this answers my problem.

Comment: Can you also help me answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67035414/jmeter-extracting-json-response-with-special-spaces-characters?noredirect=1#comment118515623_67035414. I want to extract selected parameter without using regular expression extractor, because there's a special character. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [prev](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to change sampler name and `vars` to get variable value

```
prev.setSampleLabel(vars.get("name"));
```

> prev - (SampleResult) - gives access to the previous SampleResult